# PHP MySQL find same values over different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 different tables (2017,2018,2019,2020).

In every table there is a structure like this:
id, name, stars,...

I want to identify the ids where the value star=4 over all the tables mentioned above.
The output would be like:

| ID | tables |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4 |
| 5678 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

id 1234 4x (this means the id is in 2017-2020)
id 5678 3x (the id only is in 3 of 4 tables)
and so on ...

Unfortunately I have no idea how the sql command should look like.
I tried sth. like:  `SELECT id FROM '2019' JOIN '2020' WHERE stars=4`

Help would very be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a database design flaw. Your database is de-normalised. Anytime you find yourself creating multiple tables with the same structure, just a different name, then a big red flashing light should be going off in your head. A single table with columns `id`, `name`, `stars`, `year` would make more sense. Year is an attribute of the data, not a separate dataset. If you can have IDs which repeat in different years that's fine, maybe that's an extra attribute as well for the repeatable ID as well as a unique one for each row.

Comment: This is actually no design mistake. I am hoster of a competition which is one a year. So all results go into a database with the name of the year.

Comment: That's still a design mistake. The results can all go into a single "results" table, with the year as one of the columns in the table, then you know which rows belong to which year. Any database where you have multiple tables with the same set of columns is denormalised. The fact you've had to used this convoluted, repetitive UNION query to get statistics about all the years is proof enough of the flaw in the design. Having to add a new table every time you have a new year should not be necessary - your database should (and could) support an infinite number of years without any schema changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
select id, count(*) from (
  select id from table_2017 where stars = 4
  union all
  select id from table_2018 where stars = 4
  union all
  select id from table_2019 where stars = 4
  union all
  select id from table_2020 where stars = 4) tables
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you all! The code of Turo worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM ( SELECT id, name FROM table_2017 WHERE start = 4
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, name FROM table_2018 WHERE start = 4
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, name FROM table_2019 WHERE start = 4
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, name FROM table_2020 WHERE start = 4 ) total
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM table_2017 
JOIN table_2018 USING (id, name, stars)
JOIN table_2019 USING (id, name, stars)
JOIN table_2020 USING (id, name, stars)
WHERE stars = 4
```

And a lot of another variants. Effectiveness depends on precise tables structure (existing indices primarily).